# Foam collapsed after less than 1 day

Tags: fermentation, beginner, krausen, foam

First time brewer here.

I got a [Brooklyn Brew Shop kit for a NE IPA](https://brooklynbrewshop.com/pages/instructions-new-england-ipa) on my birthday and followed all the instructions, I thought, well. I pitched the yeast sometime in the afternoon this Sunday and next morning there was nice foam and activity in the beer, much to my delight. The instructions said the heaviest fermentation should last 2-3 days so I planned to switch the blow-off tube for the airlock on Wednesday.

However by Monday afternoon, the foam subsided and a deposit formed. This picture shows how the fermenter looks like since Monday yesterday.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/4uvBvtWtwcf9YG8K9

I did a bit of reading around and while most comments tend to be positive that the beer should be fine, I am worried that there is a sediment formed after only 24 hours. Most posts suggest checking the gravity but since it's a beginners kit it didn't come with a hydrometer.

Basically, I have 2 questions about this:

- Does the fact the sediment formed mean the yeast is kaput?
- If not, what will the impact be on the final product?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foam you are talking about is normally called "kraüsen" (mostly) or "barm" (sometimes, UK). The sediment at the bottom is excess yeast and trub that has dropped out of your beer. Even if a fermentation is going on for a longer time, this layer will form, so do not worry about that.

Looking at the picture, I see that you had a very vigorous fermentation. This is noticeable by the specks of yeast on the fermenter glass in the upper part. I would think that your fermentation was done at a higher temperature than normally would be used, which should be between 18° C and 21° C, which would be ideal. Also the fact that your fermentation is finished this fast is an indication of this.

Like Charlie Papazian says, "Relax, don't worry, have a homebrew".

Replace the blow-off tube with the airlock, and let the fermentation finish. If you need to add dry hops, add them now.

Since you don't have a hydrometer, check the speed of the airlock bubbles. If they take more than 30 seconds, consider it fit to continue with bottling.

I would say, buy a hydrometer in the meantime, but since this is a small kit, and a NEIPA, I would advise against taking samples, because you will lose too much beer, and NEIPA is sensitive to oxidation.

Good luck with your birthday present!

Comment: Cheers @chthon! Yes, that makes sense since yesterday and sunday were particularly warm days! That little alcove is also quite warm, so I'll try and find somewhere cooler.`